# How can I create a Rails form based on an object using HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a model named Client and controller that looks like this

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
def new
  @client = Client.new
  @client.name = "New Guy"
end
end
```

and I am using HAML, what will my view need to look like to render a form based on this.

I have this

```
%p= @client.name
-form_for :client, @client do |c|
 c.label :c.name
 c.text_field :c.name
```

but my html ends up looking like this

```
<p>New Guy</p>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/client/new" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="orGtE1V05QIaye5kSsAi5SBdEAV0AJX9uZYUzHw5P64=" /></div>
  c.label :c.name
  c.text_field :c.name
</form>
```

**Update:**
Thanks for the answers. when I change the view to

```
%p= @client.name
-form_for :client, @client do |c|
  = c.label :c.name
  = c.text_field :c.name
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `name' for :c:Symbol

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: %p= @client.name
2: -form_for :client, @client do |c|
3:   = c.label :c.name
4:   = c.text_field :c.name
```

If I comment out lines 2,3, and 4 The name prints out fine. What am I missing?

**Update 2:**

If I change the view to

```
%p= @client.name
-form_for :client, @client do |c|
 c.label :name
 c.text_field :name
```

no more error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `=` before the ruby function calls, so that they're evaluated.

```
%p= @client.name
-form_for :client, @client do |c|
  = c.label :c.name
  = c.text_field :c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this:

```
%p= @client.name
-form_for :client, @client do |c|
  =c.label :c.name
  =c.text_field :c.name
```

This doesn't take into account any visual formatting of course...

Comment: You'll get an error for this one as SO has added an extra tab before -form for :)

Comment: yep, missed that in the cut n paste. I was focused on the '=' signs. Edited the answer to account for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
%p= @client.name

- form_for :client, @client do |c|
 = c.label :c.name
 = c.text_field :c.name
```